# XML Schema Children With the Same Element

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am trying to write an XML schema for a server that accepts images. The images should either all have a mask or none should.

I would like to produce an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FIVR>
  <meal>
    <media>
      <image2D filename="filename1">
        <mask filename="filename1" />
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename2">
        <mask filename="filename1" />
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename3">
          <mask filename="filename1" />
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename4">
          <mask filename="filename1" />
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename5">
         <mask filename="filename1" />
      </image2D>
    </media>
  </meal>
</FIVR>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FIVR>
  <meal>
    <media>
      <image2D filename="filename1">
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename2">
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename3">
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename4">
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename5">
      </image2D>
    </media>
  </meal>
</FIVR>
```

But if some image2D elements have a mask child element but others dont, validation should fail. E.g the following should be rejected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FIVR>
  <meal>
    <media>
      <image2D filename="filename1">
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename2">
        <mask filename="filename1" />
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename3">
          <mask filename="filename1" />
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename4">
      </image2D>
      <image2D filename="filename5">
      </image2D>
    </media>
  </meal>
</FIVR>
```

Can I express this using an XSD schema?

The schema I have right now looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="FIVR">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="meal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="media" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="image2D" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="5" >
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:element name="mask">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:attribute name="filename" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:all>
                    <xs:attribute name="filename" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to declare media as taking *either* a sequence of maskless images, or a set of images with masks.  Since these two flavors of image have different validation behavior, it's simplest if you give them different names.  Then the content model becomes something like

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:element ref="image2D-mask" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xs:element ref="image2D-nomask" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:choice>
```

The root of your difficulty is the desire to use the same name for two different things.

Comment: I like this approach more than my Schema 1.1 `xs:assert` answer if OP has latitude to redesign in this way.  +1

Answer (score 1):

**If you're using XML Schema 1.1**, you can [specify co-occurrence constraints](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/) via XPath 2.0 using `xs:assert` like this (untested):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="my/sample/namespace"
           xmlns="my/sample/namespace"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="FIVR">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="meal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="media" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element name="image2D" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="5" >
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:all minOccurs="0">
                          <xs:element name="mask">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:attribute name="filename" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:all>
                        <xs:attribute name="filename" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:choice>
                  <xs:assert test="(count(image2D/mask) = 0) or (count(image2D/mask) = count(image2D))"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**If you're using XML Schema 1.0**, you cannot express such a constraint in the schema, but you could use [Schematron](http://xml.ascc.net/resource/schematron/) or check it at the application level.